# How to create a blur with a linear gradient for a Decoration Image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make A linear gradient blur for background pic. And I have to use Box Decoration >> DecorationImage like this

```
Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
       gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter, colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black.withOpacity(0)], stops: [0.4, 0.75]),
       image: DecorationImage(
         image: AssetImage("p1.jpg"),
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
       ),
     ),
     child: BackdropFilter(
       filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
       child: Center(
         child: box.app._widgetOptions.elementAt(box.app._selectedIndex).widget,
       ),
     ),
   ),
```

We can do the blur effect using BackdropFilter, but there is no way "That is know of " to apply gradient, it is usually done by using ImageFiltered  and ShaderMask like this

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  fit: StackFit.expand,
  children: <Widget>[
   Image.network(
            image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter),
     ImageFiltered(
              imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
              child: ShaderMask(
                shaderCallback: (rect) {
                  return LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black.withOpacity(0)],
                      stops: [0.4, 0.75]).createShader(rect);
                },
                blendMode: BlendMode.dstOut,
                child: Image.network(
                    image,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter),
              )
    ),
  ])
```

but DecorationImage Takes `ImageProvider<Object>` not a ImageFiltered

[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cMo7.jpg)